# Invalid authorization specification and Invalid connection string attribute

Tags: c#, winforms

I am getting the following error "Invalid authorization specification, Invalid connection string attribute"

```
 //namespaces
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.ComponentModel;
  using System.Data;
 using System.Drawing;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text;
 using System.Windows.Forms;
 using System.Data.SqlClient;
 using System.Configuration;
 using System.IO;
 using System.Data.OleDb;

  namespace Database1
 {
   public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public bool IsValidConnectionForPrinting()
    {
      //string declaration  
        string str = @" Provider = SQLOLEDB; Data Source = sekhar; Database = DMS; UserId = sa; Password = 123";


         //Oledbconnection to database           
        OleDbConnection oleDbcon = new OleDbConnection(str);

         try
        {
            oleDbcon.Open();
            MessageBox.Show("hai");
            oleDbcon.Close();
        }
       //Exception 
     catch (Exception ex) 

        {
            if (ex.Message.StartsWith("Invalid object name"))
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.Replace("Invalid object name", "Table or view not found"), "Connection Test");
            }
//Connection 
  private void btnConnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsValidConnectionForPrinting())
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Connection succeeded", "Connection Test");
        }
       }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which line does the error appear on? Maybe your connecting string is bad?

Comment: oleDbcon.Open();
 getting error when connection is trying to open

Comment: maybe instead of `Database` you need `Initial Catalog`

Comment: String str = @" Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=;Initial Catalog=;Integrated Security=SSPI;User ID=;Password=";             I tried with this string and the issue has been resolved ..

Comment: perhaps V4Vendetta should post this as an answer so user1312412 can reward it

Comment: I got the same error after reusing a connection string that wasn't intended for ole db. Changing the `User=XYZ` to `User Id=XYZ` fixed it. You may also decide to use windows authentication, in which case you can add `Integrated Security=SSPI` and remove the `User Id` property.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a connection string that does not include `Database` or `Initial Catalog`, and then calling something like:

```
oleDbcon.ChangeDatabase("DMS");
```

This is because, as you have already experienced, different database drivers use different syntax for referring to the database in the connection string.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error and it turned out the code path had not connected to the database.

Worth checking.